# How to do async work as part of web service?

Tags: c#, web-services, iis, asynchronous

I'm coding web service A and calling web service B.

Once I validate the input to A I want to **return** a success code and **then** invoke B.

Ways I'm considering:

- Seeing if I can spawn a worker thread that would complete after A returns.
- Coding an agent or service to call B and using a reliable Queue to transfer the validated parameters.

The runtime context is a Service.svc hosted by an ASP.NET web app.

How should I do this?

**Update**: I just want to say that the answers were all useful.  I decided to mark the one that I used.

Comment: You can do it a few ways, what are you using for your web service?  WCF? SOAP? Rest?

Comment: It's a WCF web service hosted in an MVC web site.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Once I validate the input to A I want to return a success code and then invoke B.

In this case you should place the work into a persistent queue (MSMQ, Azure Bus, etc), and only then return a success code. Another system (not hosted in ASP.NET; i.e., Azure worker role, Win32 service, etc) should retrieve work from the queue and invoke B.

This is the only reliable way to do it. Phil Haack has a [good blog post](http://haacked.com/archive/2011/10/16/the-dangers-of-implementing-recurring-background-tasks-in-asp-net.aspx) on why it's a bad idea to do both parts in ASP.NET; it comes down to recycling. More info on recycle triggers [here](http://www.iis.net/configreference/system.applicationhost/applicationpools/add/recycling) and [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/tess/archive/2006/08/02/asp-net-case-study-lost-session-variables-and-appdomain-recycles.aspx).

Comment: do async web services carry the same risks described in that blog post?

Comment: Not normally. By default, ASP.NET will not send its response until all asynchronous operations have completed. So there may be a period of time (when `async` I/O is in progress) when there are no threads working on the request, but that's OK because the response hasn't been sent out yet. The problems come in when you try to do work *after* sending the response; IIS and ASP.NET simply aren't designed for that scenario.

Answer (score 2):

This link over at Code Project should give you all the information required to create a stable [Async Communication with Windows Communication Foundation](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/121345/Asynchronous-Communication-in-a-WCF-Service).

A book with a lot of handling of this form of communication:

- WCF Step by Step
- WCF In a Multi-Tier Framework

Hopefully that helps.  I'd give you some examples but that tutorial on Code Project should provide just what you need.

Comment: that article looks very good.. so the return value of the Begin call will be the success code I mentioned in my question, right?

Answer (score 1):

Your second idea is a good one. Send the async part to a Windows Service. If you need the reliability, then do it using a message queue. In any case, you can use WCF to send the request to the other service.

Answer (score 1):

The question isn't really specific to any particular service interface. Generally, your decision depends on why you want to invoke something asynchronously:

1. If you just want to give the client a quick response to a single
   long-running method call, invoke your async method and immediately
   return a token (task ID or the like) that can be used to check on the task's progress later.
2. If you have several long-running methods to execute and you mainly want to invoke asynchronously to gain efficiency through parallelism, invoke anything you can at the outset & continue with everything else that doesn't depend on a previous method. Await any tasks that are needed for your return result to be complete, or for a subsequent task to start.
3. In most of these situations, I would give the client the choice between a synchronous and asynchronous method with a status token; if they want to continue on they can check back later, and if it's important to get that result before continuing, well that's an option too.

The approach to these gets easier with each subsequent framework release > 3.5, and I trust that other answers have given you good insights into the specifics of how to kick off, move on and/or wait for asynchronous task results in c#.

Comment: yeah, these answers have been useful..  I'm in your (1) case - the client is a real time system that needs low latency, however my other requirement is to call another web service immediately after validating the inputs - since I can't control the latency of the other web service, I don't want to depend on it being low (in fact I know it takes up to 30 seconds on the first call after being idle).

Comment: Yes, you are definitely in the #1 scenario then. You want to start the task, and return an ID that can be used to check its status. Presumably the second (slower) web service call will simply be updating something that can still be seen given that ID; that's a pretty classic use-case to design around, so I won't babble on about it here; I'm assuming you have some sort of key/value cache to store task statuses in.